# Grails 2.2.1 app cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin

I am running into problems setting up an existing grails (2.2.1) project on a new mbp.  I get dependency resolution errors whenever I try to run any grails command.  It seems that it cannot resolve any grails plugins that are marked with the compile phase like below.

```
compile ":cache:1.0.0"
```

I've taken a look at the org.grails.plugins repository to make sure the plugins exist, and they all appear to be there.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why it cannot resolve these plugins.  A coworker said he upgraded to grails 2.4, got the dependencies to resolve and download to his local cache, then went back to grails 2.2.1 to run the app.  I'd rather figure this out than have to do that.

Anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Kindly include any specific errors you are getting so as to help in clearifying the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I faced the same problem with Grails 2.2.0.
I've fixed it by adding this repository to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
mavenRepo 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins'
```

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-central-repo-seemingly-missing-plugin-versions-td4658720.html

Comment: The respository should be https I tried to edit, but it's just 1 char, so I can't.